# Closing client's outputstream closes also the server's inputstream?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, inputstream, outputstream

I saw this statement at [Writing the Server Side of a Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

> ...the client responds by writing
>   something to its output stream (the server's input stream).

So I am asking:

- Closing client's output stream will result in closing server's input
  stream (and vice versa)?
- If the above statement is true, does that mean that both `Socket`s,
  in the Client and in the Server, will also close?

Please provide a justification if possible.

Comment: [`#ReadTheDocs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()). For _Socket_, for either getInputStream, or getOutputStream: `Closing the returned InputStream will close the associated socket.`

Comment: The streams are not 'directly' connected, rather, logically, when close() is called the underlying connection is terminated - this in turn closes the 'other side' as well, eg. closed stream = no more input.

Comment: @MattClark I read the docs and I understood that the associated socket will close, but the statement above confused me about a connection between client's output stream and server's input stream

Comment: So it's a *yes*? @user2864740

Comment: If either side's socket closes, the other side socket will also be closed, either gracefully, or with a connection reset, depending on how the socket was closed. TCP connections can not be broken on one side while remaining established on the other, it is continuous 2-way communication.

Comment: @MattClark Good point. I tried it and you are right. Thank you for the correction. Perhaps a flash back to my pre-Java days.

Comment: So @MattClark to clarify, if the `Socket` of the client is closed, then so does the server's `Socket`, right?

Comment: This is correct, the `Socket` connection to the client will close, but the `ServerSocket` still remains open and awaiting new client connections.

Comment: @MattClark Of course! Thanks guys!